# Counting specific records MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

I want to show the count of users which have the status 1 (see code) within PHP MySQL.

```php
<?php
// something like this
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE status = '1'");
echo "$result";
?>
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Did you try what you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as countvar FROM users where status = '1'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$count= $row['countvar '];
```

Comment: thank for helping but i get the following errors:
Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\watermeters\index.php on line 273

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\watermeters\index.php:273 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\watermeters\index.php on line 273

Comment: The variable $con has to be replaced with your mysqli connection variable - $mysqli in your case

Comment: thank you, no errors now how can i call (show) the result in like echo "" etc, im an old guy and learning

Comment: never mind lol, thank you so much for helping it works too many beers haha